# How to check the state of python TCP client socket connected to C TCP server socket?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I'm running tcp server in C and tcp client in python. Both runs in different hardware. Let us consider Hardware A as server and Hardware B as client. If i quit the execution in Hardware A gracefully, it will send a empty packet to client (Hardware B), so that client comes to know connection is disconnected. But instead of quitting directly, i directly power off the Hardware A. Now client (Hardware B) doesn't get notified with empty packet that connection is disconnected. How to handle this scenario ? How does the client know about the disconnection when Hardware A is powered off ?

Answer (score 1):

If the TCP connection is idle, the client won't know for a long time (perhaps never).

If the client is trying to send any data to the server, then the client's TCP packets will stop being acknowledged by the server when the server is powered down; the client's TCP stack will try to resend the packets a few times, but within a couple of minutes it will give up and unilaterally close the TCP socket.  At that point the socket will select() ready-for-read, and the next call to read() on the socket will return 0 indicating that the connection is closed.

Therefore if you want to handle this scenario gracefully, the thing to do is periodically send some dummy data on the socket (i.e. something that the server will simply ignore if it receives it).  That will be sufficient to ensure that the client's local TCP stack detects and handles the problem.